# Unable to import pandas: ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: No module > named 'numpy.fft.helper'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Am new to using Python and have started my independent learning. While trying to import pandas, am getting the below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import pandas as pd
>
> File
>   "...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
>
> ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: No module
>   named 'numpy.fft.helper'

I have installed pandas using 'conda install pandas' successfully. But still the issue persists. Kindly help - went through online resources, but couldn't find anything that solves this issue.

Comment: Looks like you're in the wrong virtual environment. You may want to see how to enter the conda environment here.https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: thanks! it worked... guess i installed Spyder or Anaconda 2 times in different places. Now changed the Interpreter to appropriate environment.